# Vertex colour as shader mask - Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-groups, shader-nodes

attempting to use vertex maps (either weights or colour) as a way to blend materials on one object (ie no uvs).

Right now I have vertex colours working fine as mix input (pictured), but this only appears in eevee. In cycles the material will render as (one or the other) material but no vertex weight.
[image]

Not sure if this is a node compatibility with cycles or that it requires specific input coordinates like uvs.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Vertex color works the same in Eevee and Cycles.  We can demonstrate the use of vertex color to mix between shaders as so:

[image]

Left to right: Cycles rendered preview; material (Eevee) preview; vertex color in layer.

There's not much to it, and any problems you're having are likely due to the actual vertex color or the shaders you're mixing.

If we'd rather use a vertex group for the mix, we can do it, but the most efficient way to do this is as an attribute, so we need to use a geometry nodes modifier to convert a vertex group into a shader-readable attribute:

[image]

This is as simple as directing the vertex group, as an input to the GN, into an output with an arbitrary name, not shared with any vertex group.  We can then reference this with an attribute node in our shader.  Left to right, Cycles, Eevee, weight paint overlay.

There are subtle differences between using vertex color and using attributes for the mix.  Vertex color is always assumed by Blender to be used as sRGB color, meaning that shaders do a hidden sRGB->linear conversion on any vertex color data, which isn't quite appropriate for use, like here, as non-color data.  Attributes, however, are treated as non-color data when read.  If we compared these two techniques carefully, we would see slightly different interpolation from 0/black to 1/white.

Comment: Precisely the sort of answer I was hoping for.. Thank you. Did seem to be something more basic with my setup/ I was missing rather than simples cycles incompatibility. I had considered the rgb - bw conversion but hadnt realised you could input as an attribute in that way.